# Google Calendar Issues-

Tags: google-calendar-api

We are having an issue with the API usage for our google account. we were advised by Google support to contact you about increasing our limit? We had an issue with an integrated app and it mistakenly put too many invites on our calendar. They think by increasing or reseting the usage that maybe we will be able to use the calendar.Is this something that you can help with.

Answer (score 1):

### If you want to increase your quota, you need to follow the [instructions for managing quota](https://cloud.google.com/docs/quota#managing_your_quota_console):

- Go to the Quotas page in the Google Cloud Console ([link](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/quotas?_ga=2.152865401.1382528083.1624951797-1587248099.1604047680))
- Click ALL QUOTAS in the row of the quota you want to change. In the QUOTA PANEL, click the Global checkbox.
- On the main Quotas page, click create EDIT QUOTAS.
- Complete the request form that displays to the right as follows:

  - In the New limit field, enter the increased quota you are requesting.
  - In the Request description field, enter the reason for your request. It's useful to include information such as future growth plans, region or zone spread, and any additional requirements or dependencies.
  - Click NEXT.
  - In the Contact details panel, enter your phone number in the Phone field.
    Click DONE.
- Click SUBMIT REQUEST.